# Generating a custom soft keyboard from XML: Back button not working

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to implement a custom Keyboard layout (using XML) and got it working after struggling a lot.
The issue is that I'd like to have a "Back" button (or whatever) to close the keyboard when I'm done typing. I've looked into it and found out that I could use this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_BACK

having in my keyboard xml layout the following:

```
<Key android:codes="4" android:keyLabel="BACK" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
```

Unfortunately when pushing the key labeled "BACK" nothing specific is happening. I can only see that in my BasicOnKeyboardActionListener the correct code is being propagated.
I have even tried to have the onKey() method call Visibility.Gone (or INVISIBLE) on the view containing the custom keyboard, this hides the keyboard but if I tap on the EditText then the keyboard is not shown again.

Any hint on how to approach this?

(By the way I decided to make my own keyboard because I need to change the color of the buttons and apparently there is no other way to do this - am I wrong?)

Here is my MainActivity code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    mKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.ckeyboard);
    mTargetView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.target);
    mTargetView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    basicKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return true;
            }
    });

    basicKeyboardView = (KeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.keyboard_view);
    basicKeyboardView.setKeyboard(mKeyboard);
    basicKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(new BasicOnKeyboardActionListener(this));
}
```

ckeyboard.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="33.3%p" android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px" android:keyHeight="54dip">

    <Row>
            <Key android:codes="8" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
            <Key android:codes="9" android:keyLabel="2" />
            <Key android:codes="10" android:keyLabel="3" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
    </Row>

    <Row>
            <Key android:codes="11" android:keyLabel="4" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
            <Key android:codes="12" android:keyLabel="5" />
            <Key android:codes="13" android:keyLabel="6" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
    </Row>

    <Row>
            <Key android:codes="14" android:keyLabel="7" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
            <Key android:codes="15" android:keyLabel="8" />
            <Key android:codes="16" android:keyLabel="9" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
    </Row>

    <Row>
            <Key android:codes="67" android:keyLabel="DEL"
                    android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />

            <Key android:codes="7" android:keyLabel="0" />

            <Key android:codes="6" android:keyLabel="BACK" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
    </Row>        
</Keyboard>
```

BasicOnKeyboardActionListener.java:

```
package com.example.keyboardtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

public class BasicOnKeyboardActionListener implements OnKeyboardActionListener {

    private Activity mTargetActivity;

    public BasicOnKeyboardActionListener(Activity targetActivity) {
            mTargetActivity = targetActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
            long eventTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(
                            eventTime, 
                            eventTime,
                            KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, primaryCode, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                            KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD | KeyEvent.FLAG_KEEP_TOUCH_MODE);

            Log.d("KTAG", new Integer(primaryCode).toString());
            mTargetActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(event);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPress(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onRelease(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onText(CharSequence arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeDown() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeLeft() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeRight() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeUp() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0):

What are you really trying to do?  If you want to make a keyboard that will work globally, you're going all wrong.  You need to derive from InputMethodService and use all of the functionality that way.  The way you're doing things will actually not work for a lot of stuff-  you're not actually writing a soft keyboard, you're emulating a physical keyboard.  Normal soft keyboards do NOT use the onKey calls, only physical buttons do, so various things won't work that way.  Plus you're missing a ton of features like autocorrect.

If you're trying to make a keyboard just for your app-  your users will hate it and it will never work quite right this way.  You also lose all non-english users, since they can't use language specific keyboards.  But then you were on the right track with setting the view visibility to .GONE-  you just also have to override the onClick handler of every edit text, and have it set the visibility back to VISIBLE

Comment: In fact I need a simple numeric keyboard that will work just for a single specific EditText in my application. Doesn't need to be global at all. Is this approach wrong if I need to custom color the keyboard keys? How would you approach this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the custom colors, but lets say its for a game or something and you really need the look.  For a numeric keyboard only it isn't unreasonable.  I personally wouldn't use a keyboard at all-  over complicates things.  I'd just use 10 views and override their onClick to append to the text in the edit view.  But you've already started down this road and you're pretty close-  since there's just the one edit text, overriding its on click to make the keyboard view visible again is probably quickest.

Comment: I'm making an application to be used in the darkroom while printing photographs - So I want to make sure that all the light coming from the phone display is a of a certain shade of red so that my exposure won't be altered. I'm going ahead with overriding the edittext on click method - Just curious: If I had 10 views instead, could they overlay the main application layout positioning them in an absolute way (as I would do with CSS absolute positioning) so that they looked like a keyboard? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, that's a very unique but good reason.  If you did the 10 view thing you'd be able to place them wherever you want- all of them would be part of your app.

Comment: overriding the onClick EditText event works just fine, thanks! - I do have one more question: When any single key is tapped a box pops up above showing the key that I just touched. This is something that happens even in the standard android keyboard. I'd like to get rid of this, I don't want any pop-up when I'm typing (obviously only talking about my custom keyboard). I don't even know how this pop-ups are called so that I could google that... Can you point me in the right direction on this?

Comment: I've never used Android's KeyboardView (always did 100% custom) but I think setPreviewEnabled(false) would fix that.